# How can I typeset the date/time at compile time?

Tags: datetime

For printed drafts of my papers, I would like to add a timestamp on every page with the date/time when the document was last compiled. Is there any LaTeX command that produces the current date/time at compile time? Even better, is there any package that already solves my problem?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

One can use `\today` to get the current date, the command `\currenttime` from `datetime` package to get the current time, and `fancyhdr` package to add it to every page.

Comment: Is there a version of `\currenttime` which comes from a standard class? I'm not sure if people have installed that package. I'll share my file.

Comment: they can install that package. Should be no problem. Having fancyhdr and datetime can't damage 8)

Comment: `datetime` is obsolete, you should use `datetime2`and the command for getting date and time becomes `\DTMnow`.

Answer (score 59):

Expanding on Grigory's answer, here's a MWE.  To get the date and time in a reasonable format, I found that I wanted the most recent version of [datetime](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datetime/), which is dated 2010/02/06 (the version that is on my system - from TeXLive 2009 - is dated 2007).  Using the default options for date and time format made the information too long (as it is, I decided it was better to shift the page number from the centre to the left).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[yyyymmdd,hhmmss]{datetime}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\rfoot{Compiled on \today\ at \currenttime}
\cfoot{}
\lfoot{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}
My great work.
\end{document}
```

If for some reason you can't use the 2010 version (or can't be sure that coworkers have it), a solution that works on the older `datetime` is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[us,12hr]{datetime} % `us' makes \today behave as usual in TeX/LaTeX
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{Compiled on {\ddmmyyyydate\today} at \currenttime}
\lfoot{Page \thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
My great work.
\end{document}
```

This later version also keeps the pagestyle closer to the `plain` default, you can edit of course as you like. The date will also show as "ddmmyyyy" instead of "yyyymmdd" but that's probably fine for your needs.

(edited by Andrew in response to Juan's comment - I can't resist a challenge; and then edited again by Juan to improve the example)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and example. It's a shame, though, that the version of `datetime` on TeX Live is outdated, as I can't reliably expect collaborators to also have the latest version. I'll have to hack my way through the older `datetime`.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Hope you don't mind I cleaned up a bit your example for the older datetime so that it's less hackish. ;)

Comment: @Juan A. Navarro: I guess I do have a bit of a tendency to go straight for the hack!  `\makeatletter` is a bit of a give-away.  I'll add here (rather than editing yet again) that, for this case, the obvious advantages of the newer version of `datetime` are: more formats and `\currenttime` includes seconds.

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect.

Answer (score 13):

There has been an update to the datetime package and it is now better to use: http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2

Comment: How does this differ from the answer by @GrygoryM?

Comment: @Ruben It's a different package (`datetime2` vs `datetime`). Technically it's not an update but a replacement (or alternative). @Betsalel, it might be worth expanding your answer to include an example with `datetime2` commands (e.g. `\DTMnow`, `\DTMcurrenttime`).

Comment: @NicolaTalbot -- fair enough, but let's be frank. Does it add such novelty to say use the `datetime2` macros instead of those from `datetime`? (pls: no offense @Betsalel, just trying to be honest.) In my opinion it's more a comment than an own answer.

Comment: when I added this yesterday I didn't have enough points to comment. I agree that it was only comment worthy. 

to note, when I started using the datetime package and looking the documentation up I was pointed to datetime2 which has more features.

Comment: Shouldn't the `datetime` package be overwritten with the new and improved code instead of adding a new package? This is like a non-commited upgrade e.g. `python2` and `python3`.