# Automatically include an SE flair in output document

Tags: graphics, shell-escape

Under the assumption that my machine is connected to the Internet, how can I automatically include my TeX.SE flair in my output document at compile time?

[image]

My understanding is that an SE flair is just a .png generated server-side when queried; at least, that's what I gather from the HTML code on my flair page.

Note that I want the process to be automated; I do not want to "manually" download the flair and then "manually" include it with `\includegraphics`.

Therefore, the problem reduces to including an image from the Web, as in [Can I use an image located on the web in a LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5433/can-i-use-an-image-located-on-the-web-in-a-latex-document).

However, I cannot get that solution to work for my flair. I use the following command (in TeXmaker 4.0.1, with TeXlive, on Mac OS 10.8.3):

```
"/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\begin{document}
\write18{wget https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/flair/21891.png}
\includegraphics{21891.png}
\end{document}
```

and here is my output:

[image]

**Subsidiary question**: I haven't researched this very much, but is there an easy way to produce a pdf that will automatically query SE servers for an up-to-date flair? I'm guessing this would probably involve some Javascript (which the pdf reader should enable), as in [How can I typeset the date/time at compile time?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/994/how-can-i-typeset-the-date-time-at-compile-time), but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Everything works fine here. I'm using Lubuntu 11.10 with TeX live 2011.

Comment: @Jubobs: take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88430/creating-a-url-downloading-command-to-be-used-with-e-g-includegraphics

Comment: When I try it it works the _second_ time (making wgert fetch it again to a renamed `_` version. I assume there is a timing issue that the file is not available for reading quick enough due to the buffering somewhere. Simpler just to run wget before pdflatex:-)

Comment: may be @Papiro should make an answer to gain weight if he is interested

Comment: @Papiro As texenthusiast wrote, feel free to post your own answer, and I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88441/21891) worked for me (with `-shell-escape` enabled).

Thanks to @Papiro for his [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88430/creating-a-url-downloading-command-to-be-used-with-e-g-includegraphics)!

Of course, you'll have to substitute your user number for mine, if you want to include your own flair :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand*{\grabto}[1]{%
    \IfFileExists{#1.png}{}{%
        \immediate\write18{%
            curl \detokenize{https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/flair/}#1.png -o #1.png%
        }%
    }%
}

\grabto{21891}
\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{21891.png}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does that make this question a duplicate?

Comment: Yes, I suppose, although my subsidiary question remains open.

Comment: @Jubos Your subsidiary question is about a pdf with an image that updates after compiling, if I understand correctly? I guess the cleanest way of handling this we close this question as a duplicate and you ask the subsidiary question as a follow-up question.