# Fancyhdr sets wrong headheight

Tags: fancyhdr, lengths

I am having some issues with `fancyhdr` setting my `\headheight`. The package seems to add too much `\headheight`. This is my current set up:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=0.3in,headheight=54pt,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{header}{ 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{54pt}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[C]{
\begin{minipage}[t][20pt]{\textwidth}
\flushleft
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
\flushleft
Print date: 2016{-}Jun{-}21 11:57:51
\newline 
R1023
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
\centering
Company Name
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
\flushright
Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{Large}\textbf{Title}\end{Large}
\linebreak 
\begin{large}Subtitle\end{large}
\flushleft{\begin{small}More Text\end{small}}
\end{minipage}
}
\fancyfoot[C]{ 
}
}
\pagestyle{header}

\begin{document}
Page 1
\newpage
Page 2
\end{document}
```

As you can see the `\headheight` on the first page is as set by geometry: 54pt, but on the second page the `fancyhdr` package resets it to ~70pt resulting in a lot of empty space left on the page. Is there something I am missing in the header that is increasing the size?

Comment: You should read the warnings in the `.log`. It suggests the head height to be at least 75.84538pt, not 54pt. Hence the increase from page 2 onward.

Comment: Actually `fancyhdr` does not set the headheight at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is causing different spacing between a header and content on one page only?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2394/5764)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response @Werner. I have read the warning in the log, but I am wondering what in particular causes the \headheight to be set to that value. If I surround the minipages in an \fbox the sizes do not exceed ~54pt

Comment: @VladG: How do you know this? Did you measure it by hand? Did you put it in a box and print out the `h`eigh`t`? If it's the latter, then you probably forgot about the `d`e`p`th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem stems from an incorrect `headheight` setting. One can either *remove* the `headheight` setting from [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry)'s options and see what [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) suggests in the `.log`, or set the header in a box and measure it yourself (remember to consider both the `h`eigh`t` and the `d`e`p`th of this box). The former is much easier.

The following construction is a little easier on the eyes and uses some automation for coming up with the time and date (using [`datetime2`](http://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=0.3in,headheight=74pt,headsep=0pt,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,tabularx}
\usepackage[english]{datetime2}

\DTMnewdatestyle{dashdate}{%
  \renewcommand{\DTMdisplaydate}[4]{\number##1-\DTMenglishshortmonthname{##2}-\number##3}%
  \renewcommand{\DTMDisplaydate}{\DTMdisplaydate}%
}
\DTMsetdatestyle{dashdate}
\DTMsettimestyle{default}

\fancypagestyle{header}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyhead[L]{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}X>{\centering\arraybackslash}X>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X@{}}
      Print date: \DTMtoday~\DTMcurrenttime & % http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/994/5764
      Company Name &
      Page \thepage~of~\pageref{LastPage} \\
      R1023 \\
      & \Large\bfseries Title \\
      & \large Subtitle \\
      \\
      \small More text
    \end{tabularx}% 
  }
}
\pagestyle{header}

\begin{document}

Page 1

\newpage
Page 2

\end{document}
```

The `74pt` height for the header stems from what is printed in the `.log` *without* it:

> Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt):
>    Make it at least 73.60002pt.
>    We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
>    This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I was under the impression that an `\fbox` surrounded both the `height` and the `depth` of its content. But when I add `showframe` to the `geometry` package the header goes beyond both of the boxes.

Comment: `\fbox` should, but remember that `\fbox` sets a box with a gap of `\fboxsep` between the content and the rule around it. If your header fits *exactly*, the box will run over the margins.